# Using jQuery with React

Tags: jquery, reactjs

I am just trying to print the data test foo using react. In my app.js file i have written the following code

```
/** @jsx React.DOM */
(function(){
  'use strict';

var Quiz = React.createClass({
  render:function(){
    return <div> test {this.props.data}</div>;
  }
}); // react class Quiz

ReactDOM.render( <Quiz data={"foo"} />, document.getElementbyID('#baseNode') );   

})();
```

but in place of document.getElementById('baseNode')  if i use $('#baseNode')  it throws me an error `react.js:18307 Uncaught Error: Invariant Violation: _registerComponent(...): Target container is not a DOM element.`  I have an div with id baseNode in my html Page

Answer (score 2):

`$('#baseNode')` returns `jQuery` Object, but second argument should be `HTMLElement`., `$('#baseNode')[0]` is equivalent to `document.getElementById( 'baseNode')`

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <Quiz data={"foo"} />, 
  $('#baseNode')[0]
);
```